# python convert from request python to send api in json

Tags: python, api, rest

guys I want to create a python API and request msg and get a response with JSON and send it to knime workflow and work with it

this is my script in python the fact is that he give me `json.decoder.jsondecodeError`

```
from importlib.metadata import files

import requests



url ='https://api.edination.com/v2/edifact/read'



headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '3ecf6b1c5cf34bd797a5f4c57951a1cf'}



files = {'file':open('C:\\Users\\hcharafeddine\\Desktop\\EDI\\Interchange_1654767219416.edi','rb')}



r = requests.post(url,files=files)

r.json()
```

Comment: May be you get an error response from your api which is not JSON compatible. Can we see what and how you return from your API?

Comment: i send API from program that convert edifact files to json and iwant this API from there to python and python to knime platform with python snippets

Answer (score 1):

We'll need more info to help further. I understand if you don't want to share the content of the EDI message, so here are a few things to try:

- The [EDINation](https://www.edination.com/edi-json.html) website allows you to paste an EDI message in and it'll show you the JSON output that the API will return
- It also has a sample EDIFACT document you can select and then save locally to run through your python script - you can then share the results here
- You can also use [HTTPToolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech) to inspect the API request and response to troubleshoot further.